# Is this a valid way of computing autocorrelation?

Tags: matlab

I am a beginner in Digital Signal Processing and I was trying to compute and plot an autocorrelation.

I've wrote this piece of code:

```
r = [zeros(2,1); y(1:98,1)];
r = r.*y;
```

and I wished to know if this is a valid way of computing an autocorrelation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your code contains [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), avoid them
- To calculate the autocorrelation, you do not add zeros. `y(1+lag:end).*y(1:end-lag)` would match the definition.
- Multiplying requires your data to be binary -1 or 1, not 0 or 1. I would use a version which processes logic arrays.

Answer (score 3):

How about `xcorr(y)`?  The [`xcorr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) function is part of the Signal Processing Toolbox.

Comment: I was trying to calculate by hand, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to calculate the correlation factor or the cross correlation function?
The correlation factor is basically a normalized dot product of two vectors.
The cross correlation could be calculated using the `conv` function (By flipping one of the vectors).